# Resolution problem at SBPL Lattice planner

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, resolution, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to try the SBPL Lattice planner on my map, but I have problems with the resolutions (scalling). My map.pmg has a resolution of 0.05, and in the SBPL Lattice planner is the resolution 0.025. Where can I change that to 0.05?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165716/resolution-problem-at-sbpl-lattice-planner/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The SBPL resolution is specified in the primitives file; you'll have to update the code that generated the primitives (usually a matlab program) to use a different resolution, and re-generate your primitives.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0